Wordpress: Allow file access to a custom role after restriction code in htaccess
I added this code in my .htaccess file of my site to deny access to .pdf files. I works fine.
<FilesMatch "\.(pdf)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

Now, logged 'administrator' role users are able to access pdf files. It seems that these users are excluded from that restriction code. So far so good.
UPDATE: my mistake: admin users are not able to access pdf files.
Now I need to give access to a custom role "member_role". I mean, users with this role should be able to access/download pdf file in the same way than 'administrator' role users.
I guess that I need to give the right permissions to this Role but I don't know how to do it.
How and where can I do this?
Regards,

There is no magic in the default setup that somehow disables your configuration for "administrators", however those are defined. So there has to be some factor in your local setup that you did not tell us about if those users are currently really able to access those files. Once you identified that you have you answer. But there is little we can say in this, since we do not know your setup.

"Now, logged 'administrator' role users are able to access pdf files." - but probably not by directly accessing the the file location (because that should be impossible with the above setup), but rather via some script ...? Check what URL you are actually clicking on, when accessing such a file as admin. And then see if that URL allows to draw any conclusions as to what plugin / part of WP functionality might be in use.

@CBroe you are right. I double check on this and admin users are not able to access the file. The file I need to restrict is: mysite/com/wp-content/uploads/2024/06/myFile.pdf

When you disable all direct HTTP access, then you will need to use a script to read the file content via the file system, and passes it on to the client. Within that script you will have to implement your access checks then.

@CBroe Can you please tell how can I start with the 'script' you mention. Some documentation, question, etc. Thanks

There are plugins available for this, like f.e. https://wordpress.org/plugins/prevent-file-access/ If you don't find one that you like, or don't want to spend the money for any more advanced paid ones - then you'll have to look into the matter a bit more closely yourself, do a bit more research on how stuff like this works.
